# MaskedTextBox multiline asciionly

Tags: c#, winforms

When

```
MaskedTextBox srcCodeBox = new MaskedTextBox();
srcCodeBox.AsciiOnly = true;
srcCodeBox.Multiline = true;
```

Multiline not works.

Why?

Comment: I wonder why does one need to have a multiline masked text box with ASCII-only characters :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple - it should not work.

1. `MaskedTextBox` is not supposed to be multiline.
   According to [MSDN, MaskedTextBox.MultiLine property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.multiline(v=vs.110).aspx)

   > Gets or sets a value indicating whether this is a multiline text box control. This property is not fully supported by MaskedTextBox.

   However, it is not a main problem.
2. `AsciiOnly` property disables multiline behaviour because allows only English alphabet letters.

   According to [MSDN, MaskedTextBox.AsciiOnly property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.asciionly(v=vs.110).aspx)

   > If true, AsciiOnly restricts user input to the characters a-z and A-Z. ASCII control characters are not allowed.

   Newline (line break) is an ASCII control character. In other words, `MultiLine` will not work with `AsciiOnly` even for a simple `TextBox` control.